# Why would someone use ob_start in this manner and what is the point?

Tags: php

Something is failing in the class I copied over. It's not my class, but the relevant bit that fails is:

```
class foo {
  function process() {
    ob_start( array( &$this, 'parseTemplate' ) );
  }

  function parseTemplate(){}

}
```

Does anyone know what the `ob_start` expression is supposed to do? Call the `parse_template` method in the context of a copy of `&$this`? PHP Version is `5.3.2-1`. I suspect that the class was coded for 5.0-5.2 and it breaks in 5.3? or could it be something else?

Comment: Ok, we now have a lot of responses stating that this is an ob_start callback usage. The second part of the problem is why does it fail. there's a big warning on the manual, check that the parseTemplate function contains" chdir(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))". Maybe it's that, or maybe not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument to [`ob_start`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) is a callback.

To understand what this does, you have to check PHP's [definition of callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback).

Specifically, it says

> A method of an instantiated object is
>   passed as an array containing an
>   object at index 0 and the method name
>   at index 1.

So, what this actually does is call `$this->parseTemplate();` when output buffering is complete.

I'm not sure that the reference operator `&` is needed here, though.

Comment: The reference operator isn't needed.

Answer (score 2):

`ob_start()` is output buffering, the parameter passed in is supposed to be a callback that gets called when the buffer is flushed with ob_flush(), ob_clean() or similar function.

```
// Type 3: Object method call
$obj = new MyClass();
call_user_func(array($obj, 'myCallbackMethod'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what is the output of the fail I can guess 2 things.
In version 5.3.* there is no need for referencing instances so `&$this` to just `$this`.
The other thing would be that the `ob_start ...` needs to be called before any buffer output as far as I know.

Comment: You can call it before or after output.  Doesn't make a difference.